# ClientProtocolException Android

Tags: android, exception, http-get

So I am trying to browse to a localhost webpage with my android device. When I put the following url in my Android browser it works:

```
http://192.168.x.x/timecode
```

But when I try to access via httpget, like this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI website = new URI("http://192.168.x.x:8000/timecode");
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(website);
HttpResponse response =client.execute(request);
```

Raises an Exception

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
```

And when I looked at the StackTrace I saw something interesting that I think It might have something to do with the Exception

```
org.apache.http.ParseException: Unable to parse status code from status line HTTP/1.1
```

What I intend to do is to get the content of the page I'm trying to access and is as simple as this:

```
{
"currentTime": "00:00:02"  
"videoId": "video2"
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong. I know its not because of the url because it works n every browser so Im guessing it has something to do with the HttpClient but I have no idea what.

Can someone please help me on this one ?

Thanks